# gridview datasource from object with LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have a List called `pers` that contains some objects. Every object contains an object called `Missioni` which is a List.

How can i create a datasource for a gridview using LINQ. I tried the code below but it duplicate lines.

```
var dati = (from p in pers
                from m in p.Missioni
                select new
                {
                    CF = p.CodFis,
                    Qualifica = p.Qualifica,
                    Nominativo = string.Concat(p.Cognome, " ", p.Nome),
                    MissionPlace = m.Luogo,
                    NMissione = m.NMissione,

                }).ToList();
```

Comment: The code looks ok; are you sure the contents of `pers` doesn't contain duplicates once you create `dati`? You may want to post sample data and show how you're getting duplicates.

Comment: How does it duplicate lines, please be more specific about your problem.

Comment: @Jacob You have identified the problem: the database had duplicates. Thank You for making me open my eyes.

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
__Always__ tag your question correctly!

Comment: @TaW Sorry i forgot to add asp.net to my tags

Answer (score 0):

Use [MoreLINQ](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ), which has a DistinctBy method.

Comment: this  "answer" could be a comment.